# Passing an array of strings to an $http get service, one at a time. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, http

```
  $scope.sampleData = function() {
    var output;
    $scope.sampleArtist.map(function(el){
      $http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q='+el).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        output = data;
              console.log(data.data.artists.items[0].name);
              $scope.artist.name = data.data.artists.items[0].name;
              $scope.artist.popularity = data.data.artists.items[0].popularity;
            }).then(function(){
              $http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/'+ output.data.artists.items[0].id +'/top-tracks?country=SE').then(function(response) {
        $scope.artist.tracks = response.data.tracks;
        $scope.artists.push($scope.artist);
        $scope.artist = {};
              })
            })
      })
    }
```

there is an aray of strings `["Steven wilson", "Dream Theater", "Deep Purple", "Slipknot"]`
and I need to pass each string to the $http service one at a time such that the relevant data gets displayed on the screen.

However, it only displays data for three of the strings, and displays name and popularity for only one of the three. It displays the tracks for all three.

Keep in mind that, I have another function in which a user manually passes a string, and it displays the data correctly, and I have tried passing each data in array manually and it displays correctly, so there is nothing wrong with how the data is accessed.

also, i am getting this error

```
angular.js:14328 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/js/app.js:33:53
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:133:460
    at m.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:147:313)
    at m.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:144:421)
    at m.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:148:78)
    at l (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:101:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:106:489) Possibly unhandled rejection: {}
```

Comment: you are overwriting `name` and `popularity` within each request callback, so only last request received will be available. Need more detail on how you are displaying this

Comment: but why is tracks for all getting displayed?

Comment: Create a demo for this in plunker. `tracks` is also being overwritten in code shown